# Flash Builder 4.6 always shows blank html page on debug or release run

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6, flashbuilder4

I'm having a problem with Flash Builder 4.6 premium.  I'm using the 4.6 flex sdk and creating a web application.  To test my development environment I simply add:

```
<s:Label text="TEST" x="10" y="10"/>
```

between the Application tags of the mxml file.  When I switch to design mode I can see my TEST label.  However, if a run a debug or a release test ( as web application ) I always wind up with a blank page.  I have even tried importing sample code from books that I know to be good code.  This is so weird because I have been using the program with no problem for so long then sudenly this.  I have blow a whole development day over this.

Please HELP!
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Is this program just terminally bug ridden?  I get that notion from reading the other questions.  If so, can I use the 4.6 sdk with flashbuilder 4.0?

Comment: I don't know what other questions you've read.  I've used FB4.6 as my primary Flex IDE since it came out w/o any issues.  Since you can't run your program, a few questions:  Is there some other bug preventing your app from compiling? Check the problems tab.  Is output being generated in the bin-debug folder? Is the specified URL in your project settings correct?  Have you tried loading the SWF directly w/o going through the HTML page?

Comment: Check your error log. If you don't have one yet, set it up:  http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/ Any conspicuous error messages?

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? If it's Chrome, that's the problem. Chrome does not play nice with the Debug Flash player and there are issues with Flash in general. For debug work, I suggest using another browser (IE or Firefox seem to work best).

Answer (score 1):

right click project name->Properties->select "Flex Compiler"->

there is a label "Additional compiler arguments", input "-use-network=false" in the textbox below this label.

->OK.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Clean

and check if you are running debug version of Flash Player on the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, the problem being Chrome was my default browser. In the flash builder preferences you can define which browser to use when debuging.